# Authorize controller actions with cancan in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

i have some actions in controller and put authorize for 3 actions,

```
class TestController
 def test1
   authorize! :view, :testcase1
   #do things1
 end

 def test2
   authorize! :view, :testcase2
   #do things2
 end

 def test3
   authorize! :view, :testcase3
   #do things3
 end
end
```

and in the corresponding action's view, i am checking like this

```
if can? :view, :test_case1
   #do things
end
```

So the problem is i am calling the authorize in 3 functions, can i put it like a single, same as before_filter

Comment: I didn't got. What you want exactly?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what you're getting at, but `load_and authorize_resource` is typically the best way to go. If you need to skip a controller action, you can do something like this:

```
class TestController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  skip_authorize_resource :only => :new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the class

```
class TestController
 load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

and you dont need to use authorize in every action

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions

Comment: yes, but its not for every actions, only for some actions, also i tried this load_and_authorize_resource, but in this case, it doesn't raise the exception